# Kotlin filter nested lists

Tags: kotlin, filter

I want to filter a list that has episodes of series. The list looks a bit like this:

```
[
  {
    "media": {
      "episode_number": "7"
    },
    "collection": {
      "collection_id": "26464"
    }
  },
  {
    "media": {
      "episode_number": "6"
    },
    "collection": {
      "collection_id": "26464"
    }
  },
  {
    "media": {
      "episode_number": "9"
    },
    "collection": {
      "collection_id": "123456"
    }
  }
]
```

I only want the highest episode number of each collection (serie). so the result would be:

```
[
  {
    "media": {
      "episode_number": "7"
    },
    "collection": {
      "collection_id": "26464"
    }
  },
  {
    "media": {
      "episode_number": "9"
    },
    "collection": {
      "collection_id": "123456"
    }
  }
]
```

I tried this using a filter but I can't figure out how to use the nested structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need here is to **group items by** `collection.collectionId` and then for each group look for an item with **maximum** value of `media.episode_number`. In Kotlin it can be done almost as it was said above:

```kotlin
items
    .groupBy { it.collection.collectionId }
    .values
    .map { group -> group.maxByOrNull { it.media.episode_number }!! }
```

Above solution creates intermediary collections that are not strictly necessary. We can improve the performance by calculating the max while grouping. Unfortunately, Kotlin does not provide a handy `maxBy()` function in this case, but we can create it by ourselves:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val items = ...
    items
        .groupingBy { it.collection.collectionId }
        .maxBy { _, it -> it.media.episode_number }
        .values
}

fun <T, K, R : Comparable<R>> Grouping<T, K>.maxBy(selector: (K, T) -> R): Map<K, T> {
    return reduce { k, it1, it2 ->
        if (selector(k, it1) >= selector(k, it2)) it1 else it2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
list = list.sortedBy { it.collection.collectionId }.filter { item ->
                        item == list.first { it.collection.collectionId == item.collection.collectionId }
                    }
```

(turns out they are already sorted by episode in the correct order)

I think this is one of the fastest solutions, but feel free to share more